# Pushing spliced items returns nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

I am trying to push 3 random items from an array into a new array. I use `splice()` to grab an item and remove it from the old array. When I `push()` the items, I would like to get them back in a single array.

For example:

```js
["b", "f", "a"]
```

This is my code:

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
let newletters = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newletters.push(letters.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length), 1));
}

console.log(newletters);
```

It seems like I am pushing the spliced items as arrays into the new array, is there a way to fix this?

```js
[
  [
    "b"
  ],
  [
    "f"
  ],
  [
    "a"
  ]
]
```

Comment: [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) always returns an array with the deleted items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [spread `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array from [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Or take the first element with and index.

```
letters.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)[0]
```

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
let newletters = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newletters.push(...letters.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length), 1));
}

console.log(newletters);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.concat` instead.

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
let newletters = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newletters = newletters.concat(letters.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length), 1));
}

console.log(newletters);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
let newletters = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newletters.push(letters.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length), 1));
}

console.log(newletters.flat());
```

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question at hand?

Comment: @MZ I added only one function there - [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
Аnd you could google what it is and find a better explanation

Comment: answers with an explanation, and not just a link, do better here at SO

Answer (score -1):

Use the `...` operator inside the push statement.

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const newLetters = []
newLetters.push(...letters.splice(1, 2)) // Equal to newLetters.push('b', 'c')
console.log(newletters)
```